# How to know how much percentage file uploaded to server in android

Tags: android, file-upload, httpclient, progressdialog, progress

I am using this code to upload file from my android to a server but I dont know how much of my file is uploaded( for example `30MB` from `100MB`)!
Is there any way?

```
String url = "http://yourserver";
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
    "yourfile");
try {
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
        new FileInputStream(file), -1);
reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
//Do something with response...

} catch (Exception e) {
// show error
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you have use `AsyncTask` and set `ProgressDialog` percent using `publishProgress()` method. For more detail visit this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/).

Answer (score 1):

hello for working with internet you must to use new Thread but in thread we can't access main thread so make a new runonuithread and change progress from it

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /*
            upload codes goes here
             */

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //set value of progressbar here
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```